# Iterator for reading file chunks

Tags: rust

I am trying to create an iterator for reading chunks of size `chunk_size` from a file. I have the following solution:

```rust
fn read_chunks<R: std::io::Read>(file: &mut R, chunk_size: usize) {
    let file_bytes: Vec<u8> = file.bytes().flatten().collect();
    let chunk_iter = file_bytes.chunks(chunk_size);
    // rest of code omitted ...
}
```

It is however too slow for large files. I notice the following is much faster:

```rust
fn read_chunks<R: std::io::Read>(file: &mut R, chunk_size: usize) {
    loop {
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; chunk_size]
        match file.read_exact(&mut buf) {
            Ok(()) => {
                // code for handling each chunk omitted
            }
            Err(e) if e.kind() == std::io::error::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEoF => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I return it as an iterator? I want to have it like `chunk_iter` where I can use it in conjunction with other iterators.

intuitively I want to write something like this (similar to a generator in python):

```
fn read_chunks_iter<'a, R: std::io::Read>(file &mut R, chunk_size: usize)
    -> Iterator<Item=&'a [u8]>
 {
    loop {
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; chunk_size]
        match file.read_exact(&mut buf) {
            Ok(()) => {
                yield buf;
            }
            Err(e) if e.kind() == std::io::error::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEoF => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to propagate errors? Are you amenable to the item type being `std::io::Result<_>`?

Comment: Rust doesn’t have stable generators yet, so you’ll have to make a struct that holds the parameters and state and implement the `Iterator` trait for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple iterator like this isn't too difficult since each iteration of the loop produces a single item. We just need to make a type for it and stick the contents of the loop into `Iterator::next`.

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read, ErrorKind};

pub struct ToChunks<R> {
    reader: R,
    chunk_size: usize,
}

impl<R: Read> Iterator for ToChunks<R> {
    type Item = io::Result<Vec<u8>>;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut buffer = vec![0u8; self.chunk_size];
        match self.reader.read_exact(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(()) => return Some(Ok(buffer)),
            Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => None,
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        }
    }
}
```

After that we can put together a simple trait to make it easier to call and we are ready to go.

```rust
pub trait IterChunks {
    type Output;
    
    fn iter_chunks(self, len: usize) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<R: Read> IterChunks for R {
    type Output = ToChunks<R>;
    
    fn iter_chunks(self, len: usize) -> Self::Output {
        ToChunks {
            reader: self,
            chunk_size: len,
        }
    }
}
```

Now it should be as simple as calling `iter_chunks(len)`.

```rust
let file = BufReader::new(File::open("large_file.txt")?);

for chunk in file.iter_chunks(1024) {
    println!("{:?}", chunk);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but why does the return value need to be `Option<io::Result<Vec<u8>>>` and not just `Option<Vec<u8>>` ? The only errors which occur in `next` are handled explicitly by the match statement.

Comment: Ok, It seems as if `Err(e) => Some(Err(e))` will propagate the error, so not all errors are handled explicitly. Still, I could just return `None` for all errors and it should be no need to use `std::io::Result` as a return value? (Not saying anything is wrong just confused by it)

Comment: The issue is, most readers can produce other kinds of errors in addition to `ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof`. While extremely rare, it is generally better to let whoever is implementing this trait decide how they want to handle those cases instead of silently erroring or panicking. For example, what if you are reading a file from a usb drive and it gets unplugged mid way? Other types like `TcpStream` also implement `Read` and can produce a wide range of errors during a read, but not all are fatal.

Comment: @Kevin, sure you could do that but I wouldn't recommend it. I wouldn't be surprised if you had issues later on due to an error being silently ignored. I would recommend instead replacing that case with a `panic!("Unexpected error: {:?}", e)` instead if you want to ignore that case.